# C# MVS Project: Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, iis, localhost

I have a program for class which involves C# and MVC. Upon running it in a classroom computer, the program's home page looks like this:

[image]

But, when I run the same program at home, it looks like this:

[image]

So obviously the program's resources are not loading, and I see this error when I press F12:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

For six different files, among which is the css file:

```
http://localhost:4321/Content/site.css
```

Now, I have installed IIS, so writing `localhost` on the browser URL bar takes me to the IIS homepage. But what could be causing this problem? Does this have to do with port forwarding (I have a comcast router, Arris TG862G which I heard sucks)? Is it possible to change the directory where the project takes the source files from to avoid this? Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Could the be the a problem related to using https for your site and http at home?

Comment: I don't know, but if I write `http://localhost/` I get taken to iis. If I write `https://localhost/` Chrome tells me the webpage is not available

Comment: I may be wrong but you have a production box that requires ssl. Now, you are developing locally using http. This could be the issue.

Comment: does this mean I have to reinstall IIS or enable a setting?

Comment: Can you select an image that does not load in the second picture above and left click to bring up the properties dialog then copy the url of that image. Can you access that url by posting it into your browser?

Comment: When I try to run `http://localhost:4321/Images/placeholder.png` I get this: `http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/ise500.png`

Comment: Its an image of a 500.19 error page 0_o

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your IIS or localhost. The errors are occurring when you are requesting certain external resources. The link http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/ise500.png does not have a well configured mime type mapping.

You either have to have someone rectify the error(s) on that server or better yet, download the resources you need in your project and access them locally.

Comment: lol, Actually I just realized that is a valid image of a http 500 error page...what the hell!

Comment: It also looks like your style sheets are not loading correctly.

Comment: yeah, I posted that image on my site because I couldn't display it here under the comments. That's what I get when I run `http://localhost:4321/Images/placeholder.png`

Comment: I'm starting to think something is not configured correctly on your iis. Try adding  <clear /> above your <mimeMap fileExtension=.../> in the web.config.

Comment: I did that and now I'm getting a 404 `http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/error4043.png` . Am I supposed to add this to IIS as a webpage or something?

Comment: Ok, what happens if you remove the entire  <staticContent> section?

Comment: mimeMap and all? Or just the staticContent tag?

Comment: First add this <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" .../>if that does not work  remove the whole section.

Comment: I added that, and while I only got one error, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4321/__browserLink/requestData/5ed8e7bba76146c3892fcc6fc1705526` , I still see the homepage as it first was

Comment: Man this is weird. I would just create a new web/app/bound to a app pool that is configured to your asp.net version  in iss and remove all configs except your main app configs. Start it up and go from scratch.

Comment: I tried creating a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application but the only kind of project I have under C# Web is ASP.NET Web Application. Would this contribute to the errors I have? Anyways, I tried installing MVC4 from here `http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4` and when I run the project I get no more errors, but the images and css still don't load (I'm going to ask a friend in class for a copy of his project to see how it works on my pc). And I already installed MVC4, but I'm yet not able to create a ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application (the option doesn't appear). Do I have to enable something else?

Comment: I installed SQL Server 2008 and ran the program again, and it works flawlessly... I guess I was missing supporting software!